# MYSQL Select rows in PHP by name

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code and it only works when I specify the column number!

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    echo($row[0]);
}
```

Not when I use the name though

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    echo($row['name']);
}
```

Is there something that needs setting on the MYSQL box?

Comment: Are you sure you have a `name` column in your resultset ? *(do you have such a column in your table, and is it selected)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try `print_r( $row )` for debugging so you see which column names are actually set in the resultset. Getting the associative names doesn't need to be configured in some way, but the index names need to exactly represent the column names in the database result.

Comment: Yep +1 and accept, I was being a num nuts as the row was called tablename_columnname

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array`, according to the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), fetches the result row as an numeric array or as an associative array, depending on the second parameter. By default, this is `MYSQL_BOTH`, so you can access via both means.

It seems like the problem may like with your query, specifically the actual name of the column in your `SELECT` statement. Without seeing more of your query, I can suggest adding `AS name` to the first column to ensure it is the actual retrieved column name. `print_r` will print the array for further debugging.